# CircleCI filter pull requests

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, circleci, git-flow

I have a Gitflow branch structure like this:

- master (default)

  - develop
  - feature/header

I'm using CircleCI with the "Only build pull requests" feature enabled. With this enabled, it will build all pull requests and always build the default branch. So the following happens:

- PR created from `feature/header` into `develop` which runs CircleCI tests
- After merge, a PR from `develop` into `master` also runs CircleCI tests
- After merge, a full CircleCI build and deploy is triggered since `master` is the default branch

My issue is that I want `develop` to be my default branch, since 99% of PRs created in Gitflow go into `develop`. Is there a way to disabled "Only build pull requests" and filter workflows to run on pull requests in the CircleCI `config.yml` file?

One of my workflows looks like this (already filtering by branch):

```
deploy_qa:
    jobs:
        - checkout:
            filters:
                branches:
                    only: master
        - dependencies_production:
            requires:
                - checkout
        - build_production:
            requires:
                - dependencies_production
        - deploy_qa:
            requires:
                - build_production
        - restart_qa:
            requires:
                - deploy_qa
```

Answer (score 1):

No there is not.

If you want "develop" to be your default branch, that needs to be changed on GitHub which is where the default branch is stored.

Otherwise, just build branches. It doesn't hurt to build branches always. That's more testing, which is good. If you want, you can check at the beginning of a build if it's a PR or not and if it isn't, just quit the build.

Comment: It seems CircleCI is not setup to work well with one of the most common branching models then, which is a shame. How would you test if the build is a PR or not?